# React Native Picker: Filter Specific and Duplicate Item

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, react-native-picker-select

I am using [React Native Picker](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker/).

I am calling an API which returns a list of `State` and `City`.

> - For now, there are two `State`: `Kuala Lumpur` (`state: 14`) and `Selangor`    (`state: 10`)
> - `state: 14` has two `City`: `Kuala Lumpur` (`city: 262`) and `Sungai Besi` (`city: 263`)
> - `state: 10` has one `City`: `Puchong` (`city: 256`)

**The JSON data looks like this:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "city": "262",
            "state": "14",
            "city_desc": "Kuala Lumpur",
            "state_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "city": "263",
            "state": "14",
            "city_desc": "Sungai Besi",
            "state_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "city": "256",
            "state": "10",
            "city_desc": "Puchong",
            "state_desc": "Selangor"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my app, when I call the API, the Picker loads all the `State` and `City`.

> However, is there anyway I can filter the `State` and `City` where I
>   ONLY want to show the `City` based on the `State` selected?
>
> i.e. If I select `state: 14`, the picker should ONLY show `city: 262` and `city: 263`
>
> or If I select `state: 10`, the picker should ONLY show `city: 256`
>
> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** For now there are only two `State` in the data BUT in the future I will be adding multiple `State` which will consists of multiple `City` each. For example: `state: A` will have 5 cities, `state: B` will have 3 cities etc.

Please do let me know if there's any efficient way of filter `City` based on `State` selected and as always all help would be highly appreciated.

**Code snippet provided below:**

```
class ClientScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pickerValueState: null,
            dataState: [],

            pickerValueCity: null,
            dataCity: [],

            isLoading: true,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('ComponentDidMount()');
        this.apiStateCity();
    }

    apiStateCity() {
        let self = this;
        AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_c/c_State_City/',
                responseType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                    'Authorization': keyValue,
                },
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log('apiStateCity Response: ', response.data.data);
                    self.setState({
                        dataState: response.data.data,
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error (1st): ', error);
                });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('Error (2nd): ', error) //Display error
        });
    }

    stateList() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Select Location</Text>
                <Text>State</Text>
                <View>
                    <Picker
                        mode="dropdown"
                        selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueState}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ pickerValueState: itemValue });
                            console.log('State selected (itemValue): ', itemValue);
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            this.state.dataState.map((item, key) => (
                                <Picker.Item label={item.state_desc} value={item.state} key={key} />)
                            )
                        }
                    </Picker>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    cityList() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>City</Text>
                <View>
                    <Picker
                        mode="dropdown"
                        selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueCity}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                            this.setState({ pickerValueCity: itemValue });
                            console.log('City selected (itemValue): ', itemValue);
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            this.state.dataState.map((item, key) => (
                                <Picker.Item label={item.city_desc} value={item.city} key={key} />)
                            )
                        }
                    </Picker>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>BookingApp</Text>
                <View>
                    {this.stateList()}
                    {this.cityList()}
                    {this.button()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot from the App:**

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var A = {
    "data": [
        {
            "city": "262",
            "state": "14",
            "city_desc": "Kuala Lumpur",
            "state_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "city": "263",
            "state": "14",
            "city_desc": "Sungai Besi",
            "state_desc": "Kuala Lumpur"
        },
        {
            "city": "256",
            "state": "10",
            "city_desc": "Puchong",
            "state_desc": "Selangor"
        }
    ]
};

let B= A.data.filter( item => item.state === '14');
console.log(B);
```

Comment: I just want to clarify that the data is being returned from an API. Currently there are only two `State` but in the future there will be more. In your solution, you are only showing to filter one `State` out of many. Could you provide an example where I will be able to better filter `City` based on the `State` selected? Thank you. _PS_ I have  updated the OP with additional example.

Comment: @Tim noted. Updating it now.